# SAS graph/ map legend formatting

Tags: sas, legend, proc

I have searched all over looking for map legend formatting but can't find the answer to my problem. Does SAS have a feature to display legend as a group as indicated below?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffiy2.png)

Thank you

Comment: Not easily. If you post over on communities.sas.com in the Graph forum, hopefully one of the SAS developers can comment. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Graphics-Programming/bd-p/sas_graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEGEND` statement does **not** have options that allow you to draw the 'desired' legend you have shown (named grouped range categories).

Desired:
[image: Image of desired legend - grouped range categories] Doable: [image: A SAS Legend]

You would have to use some data preprocessing and `annotate` data to draw the desired legend.

Consider this sample code that uses `gmap` to draw a `choro` map of simulated walked paths across a grid.  The legend of the map is of the 'doable' nature.  A `choro` map legend for a numeric response variable will list a value range next to each ranges boxed color.  A custom format is used in a `PUT` function call to map a numeric response variable to it's realized categorical value. The categorical variable is type string and `choro` map legend will list only the value.

[image: Sample choro map of paths walked]

```
%let H_MAX = 88;
%let V_MAX = 50;
%let C_MAX = 4250;
%let P_MAX = 1250;
%let H_CYCLE = 1.5;
%let H_JITTER = 5;
%let V_JITTER = 8;
%let PI = CONSTANT('PI');
%let PI2 = (2 * &PI);
%let PI2K = (2 * &PI * &H_CYCLE);
%let PIK = (&PI * &H_CYCLE);

data grid;
  do v = 0 to &V_MAX-1;
  do h = 0 to &H_MAX-1;
    id + 1;
    * data for clockwise edges of a unit square;
    segment = 1;
    x = h  ; y = v  ; output;
    x = h  ; y = v+1; output;
    x = h+1; y = v+1; output;
    x = h+1; y = v  ; output;
  end;
  end;
  stop;
run;

data paths (keep=id pid stepid ix p x y v h type weight);
  type = 'S'; weight = 1;
  do _n_ = 1 to &P_MAX;
    pid + 1;
    do ix = 0 to &H_MAX-1;
      p = ix + &H_JITTER * ranuni(123) - &H_JITTER / 2;
      x = p * &PI2 * &H_CYCLE / &H_MAX;
      y = &V_MAX / 2 + &V_MAX / 2.5 * sin ( x );
      y = y + &V_JITTER * ranuni(123) - &V_JITTER / 2;

      v = floor ( y ) ;
      h = floor ( p ) ;

      id = v * &H_MAX + h + 1;

      stepid + 1;
      output;
    end;
  end;

  type = 'C'; weight = 1;
  do k = 1 to floor ( &H_CYCLE / 0.5 );
    pid + 1;
    x = &PI * ( k - 0.5 );
    p = x / &PI2 / &H_CYCLE * &H_MAX ;

    if mod(k,2) then do;
      y = 1 / 3 * &V_MAX; 
    end;
    else do;
      y = 2 / 3 * &V_MAX; 
    end;

    do _n_ = 1 to &C_MAX;
      theta = &pi2 * ranuni(123) ;
      theta = _n_ * &pi2 / &C_MAX ;

      dx = &V_MAX / 6 * cos(theta) * ranuni(123);
      dy = &V_MAX / 6 * sin(theta) * ranuni(123);

      v = floor ( y + dy + ranuni(123) * &V_JITTER - &V_JITTER / 2) ;
      h = floor ( p + dx + ranuni(123) * &H_JITTER - &H_JITTER / 2) ;

      id = v * &H_MAX + h + 1;

      stepid + 1;

      output;
    end;
  end;

  type = 'L'; weight = 250;
  do k = 1 to floor ( &H_CYCLE / 0.5 );
    pid + 1;
    x = &PI * ( k - 0.5 );
    p = x / &PI2 / &H_CYCLE * &H_MAX ;

    if mod(k,2) then do;
      y = 1 / 3 * &V_MAX; 
      dy = 1;
      steps = &V_MAX * 5 / 6 - y;
    end;
    else do;
      y = 2 / 3 * &V_MAX; 
      dy = -1;
      steps = y - &V_MAX * 1 / 6;
    end;

    do _n_ = 0 to steps;
      y + dy;

      v = floor ( y ) ;
      h = floor ( p ) ;

      id = v * &H_MAX + h + 1;

      stepid + 1;

      output;
    end;
  end;

  * every id draws the grid;
  type = '*'; weight=1;
  pid + 1;
  do id = 1 to &H_MAX * &V_MAX;
    output;
  end;
  format pid stepid id 6.;
run;

proc freq noprint data=paths;
  table id / out=stepsfreq (keep=id count);
  weight weight;
run;

proc format;
  value step_count_category
     1 = 'None'
     2 -  5 = 'Fewest'
     6 - 15 = 'Fewer'
    16 - 25 = 'Few'
    26 - 35 = 'Lowest'
    36 - 45 = 'Low'
    46 - 60 = 'Moderate Low'
    61 - 75 = 'Moderate High'
    76 - 125 = 'High'
   126 - 175 = 'Higher'
   176 - high = 'Highest'
  ;
  value step_count_category_color
     1       = 'White'
     2 -   5 = 'cx00C200'
     6 -  15 = 'cx5BF700'
    16 -  25 = 'cx8CF700'
    26 -  35 = 'cxBAF700'
    36 -  45 = 'cxE0F500'
    46 -  60 = 'cxF7DF00'
    61 -  75 = 'cxFCB100'
    76 - 125 = 'cxFC8200'
   126 - 175 = 'cxFA4F00'
   176 -high = 'cxCC0000'
  ;
run;

proc format cntlout=stepsfmt lib=work;
  select step_count_category;
run;

data steps;
  set stepsfreq;
  count_category = put(count,step_count_category.);
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select quote(trim(cats(label)))
  into :order_list
    separated by ' '
  from stepsfmt
  order by input(strip(start),best12.) descending 
  ;

  select put(input(strip(start),best12.),step_count_category_color.)
  into :color_list
    separated by ' '
  from stepsfmt
  order by put(input(strip(start),best12.),step_count_category.)
  ;
quit;

%put NOTE: &=order_list;
%put NOTE: &=color_list;

goptions reset=all;

legend1 label=("Steps")
  position = (left middle)
  across = 1
  cframe = cxf7f7f7
  order = (&order_list)
;

ods _all_ close;
ods listing;
options gstyle;

goptions colors = (&color_list) ;

proc gmap map=grid data=steps(keep=id count_category);
  id id;
  choro count_category /
    legend = legend1 
    coutline = gray
  ;
run;
quit;
```